# Creating scatter plots with trendlines on Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I have a some scatter plots with corresponding regression lines in MS Excel similar to the one shown below.
[image]

I want to have this plot in my Latex document. I could simply insert this as an image, but the font styles would not be consistent with that of the "Latexish" text in the document. I know how to recreate scatter plots on Latex using the data, but my concern is creating the scatter plot plus the regression line with labelled equation and R value as shown above.

Comment: You could search for "regression" on this site. You could also use google and search for "latex regression". I found e.g. this https://latexdraw.com/linear-regression-in-latex-using-tikz/ in no time. Please show some effort before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your plot in PDF and import it in your latex document.

A better alternative is take that file and convert it in svg with Inkscape and edit it if it's necessary. Then, in your latex document, you can insert your image with `includesvg` preserving the font of your document.

[image]

[image]

Fig. 1 shows the Excel plot and Fig. 2 the svg file without any modification. In Fig. 3, the equation was modified in Inkscape and formatted as a latex equation.

Comment: Interesting. How do you export as .svg in Excel?

Comment: First export to pdf in Excel, then open the pdf in Inkscape to create the svg.

Comment: There are many tools: https://products.aspose.app/pdf/conversion/svg-to-excel